# How maven plugin can aggregate information from sub-modules?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-3

I'm trying to develop Maven-3 reporting plugin that will have an `aggregate` option. When this option is set to `true` the plugin has collect data from sub-modules and build a report just once - in parent module. How can I do this and where I can find documentation about it? Maybe an example of such a reporting plugin? Pay attention, it's Maven-3.

Comment: Consider using an aggregate _goal_ instead of a configuration attribute. This seems the be the preferred way according to [Maven-Site-Plugin multi module](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/multimodule.html)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Maven-JavaDoc-Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/), the [Maven-Source-Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/) and may be the [maven-license-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/license-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) but documentation you won't find. The source is the documentation ;-)